# Add clusterer to google maps v2 api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

I've been trying for quite awhile to add a clusterer to my google map but I've had no luck. I understand that I have to import the library for the clusterer to my html but beyond that I am unsure. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great (I am looking for something more in-depth than a link to the documentation for the clusterer, I've already reviewed that enough :/). This page has the code for the map that I am speaking of: www.thebboymap.info.

Answer (score -1):

This is a great [example](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/markermanager.htm) for what you are looking for.